# Perl regex negation

Tags: regex, perl, regex-negation

How do I negate this regular expression (without using `!~`)?

```
my $Line='pqr_abc_def_ghi_xyz';

if ($Line=~/(?:abc|def|ghi)/)
{
   printf("abc|def|ghi is not present\n");
}
else
{
   printf("abc|def|ghi is present\n");
}
```

Note: abc,def or ghi could be preceded or succeeded by string

Comment: I'm curious of the reason that you don't want to use `!~`. Will you tell me?

Comment: Because I am passing regex as an argument to a subroutine.

Comment: It would be a simpler solution to pass a flag to the sub denoting negative or positive. Maintain a list of regex/flag pairs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ( $Line =~ /^(?!.*(?:abc|def|ghi))/s ) {
```

I.e., it is not possible to match that pattern anywhere after the start of the string.

Comment: A little explanation would be really helpful :)

Comment: which part would you like an explanation of?

Comment: Why do I need a `^` ?

Comment: without that, it would try to match somewhere after the beginning of the last abc, def, or ghi in the string, and succeed (because it wouldn't match any of those after that point)

Comment: How do I rewrite the regex if I want to negate only one of the string say `abc` ?

Comment: change `abc|def|ghi` to just `abc`

Comment: I meant match `def` and `ghi` but not match `abc` - Partial negation.

Comment: def *and* ghi?  `/^(?!.*?(?:abc))(?=.*?def)(?=.*?ghi)/s`  if you meant match any string that does not contain abc and does contain either def or ghi, `/^(?!.*?(?:abc)).*?(?:def|ghi)/s`

Comment: @ysth - In this case, I don't think there is a reason to use the non-greedy quantifier inside those assertions. And since you have a trie, probably not outside either. But, I could be wrong.

Comment: @sln I think you are right, but didn't have time to try it; they don't hurt, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Another way, this might give you more control of the individual component substrings

```
 #  (?s)^(?:(?:(?!abc|def|ghi).)+|)$

 (?s)
 ^ 
 (?:
      (?:
           (?!
                abc
             |  def
             |  ghi 
           )
           . 
      )+
   |  
 )
 $
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to use `unless` instead of `if`:

```
unless ($Line=~/(?:abc|def|ghi)/){printf("abc|def|ghi is not present\n");}
else                         {printf("abc|def|ghi is present\n");}
```